# Construction of graph with given Wiener Index

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Given the sum of weights of shortest paths between all vertices in a graph, how can I construct a connected graph that satisfies the given sum? That is, how can a graph with a given wiener index be created?

Answer (score 1):

This question is addressed on the Wikipedia page [Wiener index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_index#Inverse_problem). Gutman, Yeh and Chen showed that there are no (unweighted) graphs with Wiener index 2 or 5, but all other values are attainable. In a subsequent paper, [Gutman and Yeh](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/136653/MathSlov_45-1995-4_1.pdf) determine which Wiener indices are attainable on bipartite graphs, and on the way explain how to prove the earlier result, an explanation which we reiterate here.

Consider the clique on $n$ vertices. Its Wiener index is $\binom{n}{2}$. Pick a vertex $v$ from the clique. Suppose we remove $m$ edges $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_m,y_m)$ not adjacent to $v$. Since $x_i,y_i$ are connected via $v$, each edge we remove increases the Wiener index by one, and so the resulting Wiener index is $\binom{n}{2} + m$. The maximal number of edges we can remove is $\binom{n-1}{2}$, which corresponds to a Wiender index of $\binom{n}{2} + \binom{n-1}{2} = (n-1)^2$. We deduce that for every $n$, there are graphs having Wiener index $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ to $(n-1)^2$. Let's list these ranges for small $n$, starting with $n = 2$:
$$ [1,1], \; [3,4], \; [6,9], \; [10,16], \; [15,25], \ldots $$
Denoting the intervals as $[a_n,b_n]$, starting with $n=5$ we have $a_{n+1} < b_n$, which is not hard to check directly. Therefore, in this way we can construct graphs of any Wiener index other than $2$ or $5$.

It remains to rule out 2 and 5. First, note that a graph of $n$ vertices has Wiener index at least $\binom{n}{2}$. Since $\binom{4}{2} = 6$, it is enough to consider all graphs on at most 3 vertices:

1. A path of length 1 has Wiener index 1.
2. A triangle has Wiener index 3.
3. A path of length 2 has Wiener index 4.

These are the only connected graphs on at most 3 vertices.